# Is there a way to get ArrowAssoc work in pattern matching?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

E.g if I want to write

```
1 -> 2 match {
  case 1 -> 2 => "matched"
  case _      => "not matched"
}
// error: not found: value ->
```

rather than the slightly less obvious

```
1 -> 2 match {
  case (1, 2) => "matched"
  case _      => "not matched"
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have just such a thing!  I like it because I find it more readable in many cases.

```
object -> {
  def unapply[A, B](pair: (A, B)): Option[(A, B)] =
    Some(pair)
}
```

Now you can do:

```
scala> val a -> b = 1 -> 2
a: Int = 1
b: Int = 2
```

Comment: Cool, let's get it added to Predef!

Comment: I have it in a file of many such extractors that I include in all of my projects, but Predef would be more convenient!  (I have a couple file like this, including one that implicitly adds a bunch of methods to collections.)